# Hermitian adjoint + diagonalizability

Tags: linear-transformations, diagonalization

> Let $T:\Bbb{V}\rightarrow\Bbb{V}$ be a linear transformation over an inner-product space. Suppose $TT^* = 7T-12Id_v$. Prove that T is diagonalizable and find all possible eigenvalues.

I managed to show that T is invertible but I don't think it helps. I would appreciate clues on how to solve this.

Comment: Eigenvalues. Thanks.

Comment: $T$ is hermitian right? So $T^*=T$ and since $T$ is cancelled by a polynomial with simple roots which is a product of linear terms, a well-known theorem implies that $T$ is diagonalizable ; the possible eigenvalues are the roots of $x^2-7x+12$

Comment: @Evariste I don't see the assumption that $T$ is hermitian in the question.

Comment: @Gribouillis Yeah it is unclear now, it seems like it was edited out of the title

Comment: I did, I meant Hermitian adjoint which means that for all $u,v\in\Bbb{V}$, $\langle Tu,v\rangle = \langle u,T^*v\rangle$.

Comment: Well in fact $7 T^* = (T T^* + 12 I)^* = T T^* + 12 I = 7 T$, so $T$ is hermitian.

Comment: isn't $(TT^* )^* = T^*T$?

Comment: No because $(A B)^* = B^* A^*$

Comment: OK what works is - $7T^* =(TT^*+12I)^* =T^*T+12I= 7T-12I+12I=7T$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the equation that $T$ is Hermitian, so that diagonalizability follows from the spectral theorem.

To determine the eigenvalues, use the fact that we can rewrite
$$
TT^* = 7T - 12 \operatorname{Id}_V \implies T^2 = 7T - 12 \operatorname{Id}_V.
$$

---

If you want to avoid the spectral theorem: use the fact that $(T - 3 \operatorname{Id})(T - 4\operatorname{Id}) = 0$ to show that every vector $x \in \Bbb V$ can be written as the following sum of eigenvectors:
$$
x = (4 \operatorname{Id} - T) x + (T - 3 \operatorname{Id}) x.
$$

Comment: How did you deduce the equality - $T^2 = TT^*$?

Comment: @Alon_Daniels isn't it the definition of hermitian that $T=T^*$?

Comment: I think I used the wrong term because what I know about Hermitian adjoint is that $\langle Tu,v\rangle = \langle u,T^*v\rangle$

Comment: Ok. knowing that $(T-3Id_v)(T-4Id_v) = 0$, is there a way which doesn't involve the spectral theorem? regarding the cases in which $T \ne 3Id_v , T \ne 4Id_v$

Comment: @If you want to avoid the spectral theorem, see my latest edit

Comment: Well actually you don't need the fact that $(T-3Id_v)(T-4Id_v)=0$ to show that $x = (4Id-T)x+(T-3Id)x$. This is just an algebraic step. How do you connect this to what we know about the fact that $(T-3Id_v)(T-4Id_v)=0$?

Comment: @Alon As I said, it’s a sum of eigenvectors. You should show that $(4Id - T)x$ and $(T-3Id)x$ are eigenvectors of $T$ (using the fact that $(T-3Id)(T-4Id)=0$).